# How to enable enter button in react-google-recaptcha after captcha verfication?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recaptcha, react-google-recaptcha

I need to activate enter button after captcha verified but currently it's not working. It shows `anchor:1 Uncaught (in promise) null`  below is my whole code. I'm using https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-recaptcha

```
  enterkey = event => {
    console.log(event)
    if (event.key === "Enter") {
      this.submitHandler(event);
    }
  };

 captchaValidate = (value) => {
    this.enterkey();
    console.log(value)
    if (value) {
      this.setState({ disabled: false })
    } else {
      this.setState({ disabled: true })
    }
  }


<ReCAPTCHA
   sitekey={captcha_key}
   onChange={this.captchaValidate}
   className="g_capctha"
/>
```

I think problem is with `event` because event is getting undefined when `captchaValidate` called. How can I get event in this `captchaValidate` because changing value to event it gives only some text similar like any token. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

you can make it works by making an `async` promise-based value fetching.

```
 captchaValidate = async (value) => {
    this.enterkey();
    console.log(value)
    if (value) {
      this.setState({ disabled: false })
    } else {
      this.setState({ disabled: true })
    }
  }
```